# Integrating multiple datasets for the purpose of filtering (without joins) using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to filter a dataset according to a condition in another dataset. In code it is something like this (though this doesn't work):

```
SELECT
  location_integer
FROM
  [datasetA]
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datasetB
  WHERE
    datasetB.region_start < datasetA.location_integer
    AND datasetA.location_integer < datasetB.region_end) > 1
```

In words: `datasetA` has a column of locations (integers) and `datasetB` has a column of regions specified by `region_start` and `region_end`. I want to filter `datasetA` by whether there exists a region containing `datasetA.location` in `datasetB`. If no such region exists, I want to filter that row out.

It would be equally good to create a intermediary table containing the number of regions containing each location in `datasetA` and then filtering on that, but I haven't managed to figure that out either.

Do these tables have to be included in the same dataset in order for this to work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's HAVING doing there? That should be a plain "WHERE".

Comment: @Pentium10 Yes you are completely correct, just updated the question. I think I've narrowed it down to the fact that BigQuery SQL doesn't understand `WHERE (...) > 1`, specifically the `> 1` bit. This is me trying to figure out how to express `EXISTS` as it exists in some relation databases.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any answer that combines data from two tables in BigQuery will boil down to a union or a join. Union is clearly not helpful in your use case, so you're looking at a join.

Unfortunately this is a pretty tricky problem, since BigQuery's join conditions only allow conjunctions of equalities (e.g., `a.f = b.f AND a.g = b.g`).

If your tables are not too large, you can CROSS JOIN them, and filter out the remaining rows. But that solution doesn't scale well as your tables become large, because the amount of intermediate data generated can be pretty huge.

Alternatively, if your regions contain a small number of discrete values, you could join `datasetB` with a table of integers in order to generate the list of points contained in each region, and then join that table with the location table.

```
SELECT location_integer
FROM datasetA
WHERE location_integer IN
  (SELECT (datasetB.region_start + integers.n) AS region_point
   FROM datasetB
   CROSS JOIN integers
   WHERE integers.n <= (datasetB.region_end - datasetA.region_start))
```

This approach cuts down on the size of the CROSS JOIN assuming you can guarantee that the maximum size of a region is small.

Comment: Interesting solution. The vast majority of the regions are of size < 1000, then there is a long tail of regions of size > 1000, up to 26,348. There are 3,969,906 such regions.It sounds like SQL is not the right idiom for expressing this. I'll probably try using a programming language to do a "batch" version of this computation while doing queries along the way. In other words, a `for` loop that iterates over regions and selects all the rows in `datasetA` that fit in a given region.